# Keyboard layout not usable in all programs

Tags: macos, keyboard, sparrow, evernote, ukelele

I have used [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to create a keyboard layout file (`foo.keylayout`) that lives in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts`. I used a US english layout as a base and have added some keymappings that let me type æøå (Norwegian characters) by pressing the left `alt/option` key and the `'`, `;` and `[` keys, plus some other symbols I use often – all using the left `alt/option` key.

This works great in most programs, like this text area in Chrome, in Finder, Macvim, Terminal… almost everywhere.

*But*, in Evernote and Sparrow, these mappings do not work, and if I show the current layout in the menu, I see that it switches back to the US layout when I bring one of these programs to the front. It is not possible to switch to my own layout in the dropdown menu – it switches back to US again immediately.

Is it possible to fix this – or is this because of the technologies used by Evernote and Sparrow?

Comment: Try putting the .keylayout file in Library/Keyboard Layouts and restart.  Have you asked the folks who make those apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you could try:

- Move the keyboard layout to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`. Keyboard layouts in the user library can't be selected in password dialogs or the login window.
- Change the ID from Keyboard > Set Keyboard ID... in Ukelele.
- Save the keyboard layout as a bundle instead of an XML file.

To apply changes to a keylayout file, you can for example run `sudo touch /Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/` and log out and back in.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed the ID and moved the `.keylayout` file to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts` and it works perfectly now.